# SQL Services Log On Account

Tags: sql-server-2005

we run all our SQL Services under domain administrator account, 
our network security policy is such a way that we need to change domain admin password often,
one alternative i have is that to create a domain user with admin privileges, is this advisable or should i use admin account only or are there any alternatives with better security. please give your feedback.

Regards
Praveen

Comment: +5 from developer. Keep going!

Answer (score 3):

It's not advisable to run the SQL Services as even a *local* administrator let alone a *domain* administrator.

Have a look at this Microsoft document [SQL Server 2005 Security Best Practices](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/e/85eea4fa-b3bb-4426-97d0-7f7151b2011c/SQL2005SecBestPract.doc), in particular the section titled "Service Account Selection and Management".  File type warning: the link is a .doc.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to specify a domain user during installation. This should grant that account all the privledges it needs.

For reference I think it puts the user in the 
*SQLServerMSSQLUser$ServerName$InstanceName* group during installation. The group is located under Local Users and Groups.